# WAMPServer 3.1.4 - issues connecting computers on same subnet

Tags: wampserver

I have a fresh install of WAMPServer and all is working fine with the exception of being able to connect to APACHE from any other computer on the network. I'm assuming that this is related only to APACHE here, firewall and router would be the other potential bottlenecks.

Do I only need to modify the default VHost with the additional subnet or do I need to modify both?

```
#
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
        Require ip 192.168.3     <====== add here and below or only here
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www/myhost
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/myhost">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
        Require ip 192.168.3        <========== or only here or both
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The VHOST definitions look right. But did you tell the other computer how to find `myhost` by adding the IP address of the WAMPServer machine to the HOSTS file of the other machine?

Comment: HOSTS `192.168.3.100 myhost` (where `192.168.3.100 ` is the IP of the WAMPServer PC. Once  VHOST is defined you must address that site with the ServerName or Apache wont know to look for it

Comment: I would expect to only add the `Require ip 192.168.3` to the sites that you want to access from another PC on your network

Comment: Thanks Riggs, yes accessing the server from a client would require the IP address or a modification to the hosts file on the client.

So leaving the default host for the WAMP server without "Require ip 192.168.3" has no impact on the other virtual host, they act independently?

In my example I'm having some issues connecting from another client on the same subnet and just trying to track down where the bottleneck is.. firewall, router or APACHE setup. Is there a way to test or validate that APACHE is accepting connections for that subnet?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved by modifying the Vhost file with the below and opening **port 80** on the firewall.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www/myhost
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/myhost">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local               <========== adding to the vhost
        Require ip 192.168.3        <========== adding to the vhost
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```